# Separate dictionary into multiple lists using values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've got a function that I use to populate a dictionary. The function iterates over two layers in QGIS and returns the attributes where the layers intersect and assigns the keys and values to the dict as below:

```
dict[id_code] = value
```

The contents of the dictionary :

```
{'CB000004657321': 'LT_07324_TRN1', 'CB000004657327': 'LT_07324_TRN1', 'CB000004132360': 'LT_07324_TRN2', 'CB000004132384': 'LT_07324_TRN2', 'CB000004133606': 'LT_07324_TRN2', 'CB000004133629': 'LT_07324_TRN2', 'CB000004131653': 'LT_07324_TRN2', 'CB000004130408': 'LT_07324_TRN2', 'CB000004132025': 'LT_07324_TRN2', 'CB000004131107': 'LT_07324_TRN2', 'CB000004130785': 'LT_07324_TRN2', 'CB000004132780': 'LT_07324_TRN2', 'CB000004130778': 'LT_07324_TRN2', 'CB000004132018': 'LT_07324_TRN2', 'CB000004658296': 'LT_07324_TRN1', 'CB000004657328': 'LT_07324_TRN1'}
```

The function works fine, and dictionary contains all the key-pairs as expected. In the dict there are around 15 key-values pairs. For now i'm testing with 2 possible values. What I'd like to do is separate my dictionary based on the values (split into two lists) - i.e. list_1 = ([key + vals]) where vals == 'type_a' / list_2 = ([key + vals]) where vals == 'type_b' etc

What I've tried so far is:

1. I get a set of the unique values in my dictionary with :`s_vals = set(dict.values())` which i use in the loop below.

   I'm using s_val and not just values hard coded because these can change between projects (hence i make a set unique values first)
2. I create 2 empty list :

   ```
   list_1 = []
   list_2 = []
   ```
3. I then use the function below to populate my lists:

   ```
   def fn_ouput_list(liste, dict):
       for elem in s_vals:
           for key, value in dict.items():
               if dict[key][:] == elem:
                   liste.extend([key, value])
       return liste

   list_1 = fn_ouput_list(list_1, dict) 
   list_2 = fn_ouput_list(list_2, dict)
   ```

The problem is my function produces two identical lists, with all the key-values pairs, and I don't really understand why?

I was trying to split the dictionary into two list, but might two dictionaries be better/easier?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This example isn't a [mcve] which is necessary to diagnose the problem, but based on what you've shown, you're calling the same function with the same dictionary, so why should the output be different?

Comment: @ggorlen hi, thanks for the reply. I'm trying to split a single dictionary into multiple lists, using the values - so all the key-value pairs with a value of 'A' are in list_1 and all the key-value pairs with a value of 'B'  are in list_2. Well that's the idea, looking at the function again i doubt it was ever going to work... Do you want me to post the contents of my dictionary?

Comment: Yes, please show the dictionary you're starting with and the expected result structures. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlan thanks I've added the dictionary contents and a few other comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could iterate over the dict and just build the two lists as you go,

```py
d = {'a': '000_TRN1', 'b': '000_TRN2'}

list1 = []
list2 = []
for k,v in d.items():
    if v[-1] == '1':   # if last letter of value is '1'
        list1.append((k,v))
    elif v[-1] == '2': # if last letter of value is '2'
        list2.append((k,v))

print(list1)
# [('a', '000_TRN1')]

print(list2)
# [('b', '000_TRN2')]
```

or, a little more concise but does extra work,

```py
list1 = [(k,v) for k,v in d.items() if v[-1]=='1']
list2 = [(k,v) for k,v in d.items() if v[-1]=='2']
```

**EDIT:** Based on OP's comment, consider building the lists in a dict, to save on if/else statements,

```py
d = {'CB000004132018': 'LT_07324_TRN2', 'CB000004658296': 'LT_07324_TRN1'}

z = {v[-4:]: [] for v in d.values()}
for k,v in d.items():
    z[v[-4:]].append((k,v))

z
# {'TRN1': [('CB000004658296', 'LT_07324_TRN1')],
#  'TRN2': [('CB000004132018', 'LT_07324_TRN2')]}
```

and you could pull the lists out however you want, or do

```py
alllists = [v for v in z.values()]
```

and get a list of lists.

Comment: hi thanks, that'll work in this example - but I can't write the values in the script (i.e. in your for loop "if v[-1] == '1'" for example), as i've got other dictionaries where the values could be anything  - thats why i've used 's_vals = set(dict.values())'  - this returns a set of unique values in the dictionary and why i started my for loop with 'for elem in s_vals: ' so for each unique value in the dictionary i run another loop to compare elem to the values in the dictionary and assign to a list - but it's messy and doesn't work :( - i'll try again later and update my post

Comment: thanks! I've modified it a bit to work in my function and just tested it and it work fine! Cheers!

Comment: ..I would up vote it as well  but i don't have enough rep yet...